# UWP goBack to cached page closes app

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp

I have a RootPage as root view. In my RootPage I've added this to support the back button:

```
SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += SystemNavigationManager_BackRequested;

private void SystemNavigationManager_BackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e) {
    bool handled = e.Handled;
    if (this.AppFrame == null)
        return;

    if (this.AppFrame.CanGoBack && !handled) {
        // If not, set the event to handled and go back to the previous page in the app.
        handled = true;
        this.AppFrame.GoBack();
    }
    e.Handled = handled;
}
```

This works as expected (the user goes to the previous page if there is one). But when I enable caching for one page it doesn't work anymore:

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
```

I've also tried `Required` but that gives the same result.

When I press the back button now it just closes the app instead of going back. The code for going back is executed though, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

**Update**

I've located the exception. I have a custom `TextBox` which fills the Text with a currency symbol and a space. This is essentially what creates the exception:

```
this.Loaded += (sender, args) => {
   Text = "$ ";
};
```

Note: it is not the currency symbol that breaks the app, but the fact that I set the Text in Loaded when returning to this Page (page cache should handle this now, so that's conflicting I guess)

**Update 2**

Code sample to reproduce problem. Custom TextBox:
    public class RegexTextBox : TextBox {
        private string regex = "";
        private string previousText = "";
        private int previousSelectionStart = 0;

```
    public RegexTextBox() {
        this.Loaded += (sender, args) => {
            switch(RegexType) {
                case RegexTextBoxTypes.Number:
                    regex = "^([0-9]+|)$";
                    break;
                case RegexTextBoxTypes.Currency:
                    regex = "^€ ([0-9]+|)$";
                    Text = "€ ";
                    break;
            }

            this.TextChanging += input_TextChanging;
            this.SelectionChanged += input_SelectionChanged;
            previousText = Text;
            previousSelectionStart = SelectionStart;
        };
    }

    private void input_TextChanging(TextBox sender, TextBoxTextChangingEventArgs args) {
        if (regex.Length > 0) {
            if (!Regex.IsMatch(Text, regex)) {
                Text = previousText;
                SelectionStart = previousSelectionStart;
            }

            previousText = Text;
        }
    }

    private void input_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        previousSelectionStart = SelectionStart;
    }

    public bool isEmpty() {
        if(RegexType == RegexTextBoxTypes.Currency) {
            return !Regex.IsMatch(Text, "^€ ([0-9]+)$");
        }

        return Text.Length == 0;
    }

    public void ClearText() {
        if(RegexType == RegexTextBoxTypes.Currency) {
            Text = "€ ";
        } else {
            Text = "";
        }
    }

    public string GetPlainText() {
        if (RegexType == RegexTextBoxTypes.Currency) {
            return Text.Substring(2, Text.Length - 2);
        }

        return Text;
    }

    public RegexTextBoxTypes RegexType {
        get { return (RegexTextBoxTypes)GetValue(RegexTypeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RegexTypeProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RegexTypeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("RegexType", typeof(RegexTextBoxTypes), typeof(RegexTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(RegexTextBoxTypes.Normal));
}

public enum RegexTextBoxTypes {
    Normal,
    Number,
    Currency
}
```

In your xaml put this in your grid (controls namespace points to the location of the custom TextBox):

```
        <controls:RegexTextBox
            InputScope="Number"
            RegexType="Currency"/>
```

Then in the constructor of the page put this:

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
```

Make sure the custom TextBox is filled with some numbers. Then navigate to a new page and back, when navigating back it should close the app due to an uncaught exception (though visual studio won't show there has been an exception).

Comment: Can you verify if this is the app running on desktop or mobile? If it's mobile, can you confirm if the app is in the multitasking window by pressing and holding back? If it is, it appears that the handling of the back requested isn't working correctly.

Comment: @JamesCroft92 This is running on mobile. The app is not in the multitasking window when pressing back on the second page. When I press the back button on the first page it is in the multitasking window

Comment: instead of your handled = true, could you please try just putting e.Handled = true there instead. It could be that something in your page navigation is taking too long.

Comment: @JamesCroft92 This gives the same result. I think it could have something to do with memory. Because if I goBack from a different page it works like expected. Only on this specific page it closes the app. I'm not doing anything interesting though, only a database call

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at what you might be doing in your page that you're navigating to then. Try debugging the navigated to method if you're doing anything there and just see if something is throwing an exception that is causing the app to close.

Comment: @JamesCroft92 I've commented all the code in the second page now and it still closes the app. I'll have a look at the navigatedTo method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121039/discussion-between-jamescroft92-and-kevin-van-mierlo).

Comment: @JamesCroft92 I've edited my question with a small code sample of what goes wrong.

Comment: I made a sample, but didn't reproduced your problem. Could you please share a basic demo that can reproduce this problem?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT I have edited my question with some sample code which is causing the crash. You should have the custom textbox filled to recreate the crash